# Set object property (string) as Text Index

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I know from the mongodb docs that we only can set strings or arrays of strings as text indexes for future searches. I want to know if it's possible to have as index an string which is a string property of an object. For example:

```
Person: {
 name: String
}
```

Could be name a text index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you definitely can:

```
db.collection.createIndex({'Person.name': 'text'});
```

In Mongoose:

```
schema.index({'Person.name': 'text'});
```

Comment: Great. It works. The thing is I have a more complex issue. The schema is `overview: {type: {blocks: [{ key: String, data: {}, text: String}]}}` and I want to search by the text field, inside the  "blocks". The thing is that I have an array of objects, and I want to search inside every 'text' field of every object of the array.

Comment: Maybe I should concat every text string and put it in another field to make the search easier but you know, I don't want to repeat information

Comment: I've tested it right now: indexing such a document still works. As it comes to the performance - you have to benchmark it. It may really change, depending on your data characteristic.

Comment: How was your query to test it? I tried with `db.collection.createIndex({'overview.type.blocks.text': 'text'})` and had no results

Comment: Creating index won't return anything, but create an index (well, technically it will, but it's not the matter). You have to use the [`$text`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#op._S_text) operator: `db.collection.find({$text: {$search: 'search this text'}})`.

Comment: Yes i'm using the $text operator and it works with all fields (arrays and strings) but not with this one. For example if I create:  `db.collection.createIndex({'name': 'text', 'array': 'text', 'overview.type.blocks.text' : 'text'})` it works when I search by name or array, but it doesn't work if I search by the string that is inside overview.type.blocks.text

Comment: Maybe your search criteria are not matching the text? Text indexes are kind of special when it comes to matching. I've used such index and it worked as a normal text index.

Comment: Silly mistake. it was `overview.blocks.text`. **It's working perfectly**. Thank you for your help!